# How can I get user's country flag on my site

Tags: php, html, jsp

I wanna display user's/visitor's country flag on my site.

I am using different technologies like php,jsp and simple html. So I want a code which by placing on my site, visitors can see and it should run in all platform.

In short I want country detection API. If anybody can help me, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: The API also returns the user's country flag as a png file and an emoji flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My service, [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co?utm_campaign=stackoverflow-answer-19768023&utm_medium=answer&utm_source=stackoverflow) provides an IP Geolocation API on https://api.ipdata.co and serves flags on for example https://ipdata.co/flags/cu.png.

All you have to do is know your visitors' country's iso code and you can fill it in

```
ipdata.co/flags/country-code.png
```

You can of course get the user's country code by calling https://api.ipdata.co/user-ip.

Sample embed;

```
<img src="https://ipdata.co/flags/us.png" alt="US Flag">
```

Gives

[image: US Flag]

**Edit**

We now also provide you with the country emoji flag and country emoji unicode.

Answer (score 9):

Source :

http://www.shorter.in/#flag

```
<a href="http://www.shorter.in/#flag" target="_blank">[![][2]][2]
```

Example for the code given above.

[image: a busy cat]

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Its nice but image is too small :(

Comment: The site is no longer active and now redirects to some phishing or ad site

Answer (score 4):

Yeah there is something already available and you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Check this thing out.

```
 http://api.hostip.info/flag.php?ip=12.215.42.19
```

Grab your user's IP using PHP and pass it to the API.

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

### Putting it all together

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "<img src='http://api.hostip.info/flag.php?ip=$ip' />";
?>
```

Comment: Or just do `<img src="http://api.hostip.info/flag.php"/>` and let them determine the IP

Comment: Yeah i was typing that whilst you posted :)

Comment: Blows that their API was shot down :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the IP of visitor.

   ```
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
       $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
   } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
       $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
   } else {
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   }
   ```
2. Use ip2location to find the country of the user.

   http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/
3. Compare the resulting country to a list of images and display the matching image.
   I suggest using a database to store the country name and the path to the associated image.

Comment: The IP address of the user does not always equal the country of the user, so you will not get the user's country, but a quite good guess of it.

Comment: @FredrikPortström that is true. If there is a significantly more accurate way to do this, I am interested as well.

Comment: @Patrick Geyer 

Buddy thanks a lot for reply, but as I mentioned I want to use same code on different technologies like php, jsp and plane html.
can u help me at this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GeoIP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) and then map the country in question to a given icon.

```
$countryName = geoip_country_name_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $countryName;
```

Note that getting the country via IP is not exact.